# Magento Configurable options not showing in drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, conflict, conflicting-libraries

I have a Magento store that uses two different templates. One for desktop version and the other for all other mobile devices. I used the Exception method to change the templates based on the variables in the exception list. I also have a large number of configurable products. These work just fine on the main desktop theme. All the options show and it goes through to checkout easily.

The problem is on the other theme. I get all the options for the different attributes showing on the product page but when I click the drop downs none of the options have been loaded. This happens on all products.

I am convinced it is a jQuery conflict issue as I have searched Google and this seem s to be a popular problem. I have however, disabled all my jQuery scripts allowing only prototype to run and still I get this problem.

Has anyone expirienced this and had an alternative or is there something else I could be missing?

The theme is Zonda and I've also tried using jQuery no conflict but unless I'm using it wrong it has not helped.

Comment: Try to use firebug to find exact location of conflict ...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Firebug, how would I go about this?

Comment: You could try installing a chrome extension pretending to be a mobile browser and then use the developer tools to see what script errors you're getting